# How is the ends of a bandpass filtered signal reliable after applying the cosine taper?

Tags: filters, window-functions, filtering, bandpass, window

A taper function decaying to zero at ends such as a cosine window is routinely applied to the signal before bandpass filtering to reduce end effects. Obviously the window alters the waveform.

So, as for the filtered waveform, how is it reliable near the beginning and end?

how does the the decay ratio of the window (e.g. 5%, 10% ...) influence? It's selected arbitrarily or by some criteria?

In the filtering functions of matlab and scipy, some extrapolation is applied to the ends of the signal to match their slope. In such situations, is the windowing still necessary?

Comment: Can you give an example that shows where tapering is "routinely applied"?  I've never applied a taper for filtering.

Comment: @PeterK. For instance, [link](http://krischer.github.io/pyadjoint/example_dataset.html#data-processing) . there are also some examples tapering after the bandpass filtering as [link](http://www.engr.uky.edu/~donohue/audio/Arrays/audioIm2D.m)

Comment: Neither of those links are doing filtering.  Both are doing [spectral estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_density_estimation), which generally can benefit from windowing.

Comment: @PeterK. other two places mentioning the taper [For best results, make sure the sequence you are filtering has length at least three times the filter order and tapers to zero on both edges.](http://cn.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/anti-causal-zero-phase-filter-implementation.html)  ,  [remember to
remove the mean and taper before filtering](http://www.uusatrg.utah.edu/RBSMITH/public_html/TEACHING/GG5330/5330LABS/GG5330.Lab04.pdf)

Comment: Did you imply that filtering in t domain and f domain performs differently?

Comment: The mathworks page does not say anything about applying a taper.  It says that the values should go to zero at the ends... not be forced to zero. That is why they talk about the other things they do in the sentence before.     Filtering finite duration data will generally leave a taper at the beginning and end of the output that may or may not be useful.  I'm not sure what you mean by filtering in $t$ vs $f$.  Time domain filtering involves convolution; frequency domain filtering involves multiplication.

Comment: The last word in the mathworks page "For best results, make sure ... tapers to zero on both edges" (the matlab function filtfilt is implemented in time domain). The second pdf means mean-removing and applying taper window BEFORE filtering.

Comment: Regardless, I've never seen it done without some overriding issue (e.g. noise outliers) at the ends of the signal being filtered. Right: it needs to **remove** the taper BEFORE filtering, otherwise the filtering will be wrong.

Comment: It doesn't say for you to taper.  It says that a signal that is already naturally tapered by itself will give better results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A taper function is applied for spectral estimation if the artifacts from a non-tapered rectangular window provide less useful results that the artifacts due to the tapered window.

Not tapering a finite length sub-sample vector is equivalent to rectangular windowing, which convolves Sinc shaped artifacts onto the spectrum.